# Handling unnamed docker images in AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My service is up and running in docker platform. When I list docker images in my instance, I see the following images including unnamed.

```
> docker images -aq

REPOSITORY      TAG             IMAGE ID       CREATED             SIZE
current_nginx   latest          a3e8b5ae7751   48 minutes ago      23.5MB
<none>          <none>          320523ba019f   48 minutes ago      1.52GB
current_nuxt2   latest          5b744629e956   48 minutes ago      1.52GB
<none>          <none>          ff41ec719b95   48 minutes ago      1.52GB
<none>          <none>          5ed2e390be4e   50 minutes ago      1.5GB
<none>          <none>          a2c4118d3f34   52 minutes ago      643MB
<none>          <none>          0ee04fa44ba2   54 minutes ago      23.5MB
<none>          <none>          266e831b549f   About an hour ago   406MB
<none>          <none>          7e3618333973   About an hour ago   406MB
<none>          <none>          f071bfd32b76   About an hour ago   406MB
node            16-alpine       610c0494e820   7 days ago          118MB
nginx           1.23.2-alpine   19dd4d73108a   5 weeks ago         23.5MB
```

Can someone please explain why I got these unnamed images? I only run 2 containers.

Plus I've already tried to remove one of unnamed images, and I got this error.

```
> docker rmi 320523ba019f

Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 320523ba019f (cannot be forced) - image has dependent child images
```

Comment: You're probably using `docker image ls -a`, which shows intermediate images. If you don't want to see them, don't use `-a`.

Comment: Oh I see. Each RUN, COPY, ADD command creates layers. Now I understand how I got those images. Thank you so much!